# Python login verification system

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a login system where the user types in their details and then this code verifies if the user exists

```
counter = 0
def validation():
    global counter
    print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")
    counter += 1
    if counter == 3:
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        print("You have been locked out please restart to try again")
        sys.exit()

def verify_login(username, password, login_data):
    for line in login_data:
       if ("username: " + username + " password: " + password) == line.strip():
       return True

    return False


check_failed = True
while check_failed:
    with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
        print("Could player 1 enter their username and password")
        username1=input("Please enter your username ")
        password1=input("Please enter your password ")
        if verify_login(username1, password1, username_finder):
            print("you are logged in")
```

Right now the code looks in the text file for this format:

`username: (username) password: (password)`

But now I want to add a hash code for every user so the format in the file looks like this:

`49ad2322f9a401e9e3c4ae7694b6b1f1 username: (username) password: (password)`

How would I change the verfiy_login to make it look for a random 32
characters at the beginning of every user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reconstructing the line using `"username: " + username + " password: " + password` then comparing it to the line from the text file, you can parse it by first `split`ting the string then unpacking the tokens. By splitting the line, you get access to the hash, username, and password individually as variables.

```
def verify_login(username, password, login_data):
    for line in login_data:

       hsh, _, username_from_file, _, password_from_file = line.strip().split()
       if len(hsh) == 32 and username == username_from_file and password == password_from_file:
            return True

    return False
```

Unpacking a token into `_` is a convention saying that "we will dump this value".

Comment: Im not too sure what you mean could you explain more please

Comment: Your code right now tries to build a string into the same format as you expect the text file to be in. (This: `"username: " + username + " password: " + password`) You're trying to reverse engineer it, which you don't need to. You can go the other way, unpack the line from the text file into variables, then check those variables one-on-one.

Comment: I keep on gettingt this error and I don't know why: line 13, in verify_login
    hsh, _, username_from_file, _, password_from_file = line.strip().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

Comment: Maybe an issue with the file. Edit your question with an [mcve] of your file so that we can reproduce it. The line works for me if I hardcoded `line = "49ad2322f9a401e9e3c4ae7694b6b1f1 username: (username) password: (password)"`

Comment: I only get this error when I get the username or password wrong

Comment: I've accidentally used `&&` instead of `and` in my if-statement. See if changing that fixes it. Although...  it might not fix the ValueError, only a SyntaxError.

Comment: I have already changed it to  'and' and I still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186561/discussion-between-trebuchetms-and-colkat406).